# IFS function in excel not able to work

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am not sure what is the problem, either is syntax error, or data error.

The data in 1st column F is all text. Some are in millions (with the word 'M' at the end) and some in thousands ((with the word 'K' at the end).

I want to convert all to numbers and put in column 'O'

First, I compare whether the end of the text is either 'M' or 'K' using FIND(), then i used SUBSTITUTE to remove the 'M' or 'K', and multiply by 1,000,000 or 1,000. And i put it in IFS function.

The formulae seems to work for the texts that contain 'M', but not working for 'K'.
I am unable to see why. My formulae for the first column as follows:

```
`=IFS(FIND("M",F2)>0,SUBSTITUTE(F2,"M","")*1000000,FIND("K",F2)>0,SUBSTITUTE(F2,"K","")*1000)`
```

Please refer to the screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hi @sam , your formula returns #Value error, because every time it encounters with first logical test,, and fails to read the second logical test,,, this can be handled with trapping an ERROR,, like this with `IF`,,,, `=IFERROR(IF(FIND("M",A1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"M","")*1000000),IF(FIND("K",A1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"K","")*1000,0))`,,, here `IF(FIND("K",A1),,,` is,  Test if Error ☺

Answer (score 2):

The formula is not able to move past the error if M is not found, you need to catch the error, if they are the only two values (K and M) that are going to show use something like:

```
=IFS(ISERROR(FIND("M",F2)),SUBSTITUTE(F2,"K","")*1000,ISERROR(FIND("K",F2)),SUBSTITUTE(F2,"M","")*1000000)
```

otherwise next another if function to return a value if M or K not present.

Comment: Thanks a lot Justin!

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify that the cell must shown the unchanged value if K and M are not present.

I prefer IF over IFS. Always nasty problems popping up with IFS. Try

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("K",F2)),SUBSTITUTE(F2,"K","")*1000,IF (ISNUMBER(FIND("M",F2)),SUBSTITUTE(F2,"M","")*1000000, F2))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ruud!

Comment: I have tried replacing "ISNUMBER" with "ISERROR", seems to be returning an error. The formulae is this. Why is it so? `=IF(ISERROR(FIND("K",F2)),SUBSTITUTE(F2,"K","")*1000,IF (ISERROR(FIND("M",F2)),SUBSTITUTE(F2,"M","")*1000000, F2))`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a later version of Excel that supports dynamic arrays, you can use a slightly different and (in my opinion) simpler to manage approach:

[image]

I've included additional columns to show the progress towards the green solution.

First, get the scale indicator (K or M or whatever). Then use a fixed array inside XLOOKUP to translate that into a multiplier. Then, we just need to get the number in the original cell and multiply it by the multiplier.

This is the formula in the green cell E3:

```
=NUMBERVALUE(LEFT($A3:$A6,LEN($A3:$A6)-1))*XLOOKUP(RIGHT($A3:$A6,1),{"M","K"},{1000000,1000})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Owen!